# Find text and replace, from cell with line breaks - excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have been trying to find a way to search for a specific word in a excel cell. However this doesn't work if the content of the cell has a line break.
I need to keep those line breaks and solve this using a formula.

I tried with SUBSTITUTE function, lets say the A1 cell contains:

THIS IS A TEXT
AN EXAMPLE
TO SHOW

So when I try in the A2 cell: SUBSTITUTE(A1;"EXAMPLE";"TEST")
Nothing happens

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1371415/edit) and let us know what it is you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `SUBSTITUTE()` to remove the line break.  For example:

```
=SEARCH("rest",SUBSTITUTE(D6,CHAR(10),""))
```

[image]

This insures that the word *"rest"* does not get fragmented.

Comment: Thank you @Gary's Student, but as I said, I need to keep those line breaks

Comment: @KESO  We ARE keeping the line breaks..............we are not changing cell **D6**, only removing them in the `SEARCH()` formula

Comment: you are right, however I forget to say that I need to replace the word once I find it. Thank you for your help. I will answer with the solution I found